# Error de sintaxis o conceptual ,sql , en esta pequeña query ? - nested joins ( full outer join sobre el resultado de otro join usando alias )

Tags: sql, join

La siguiente consulta SQL posee un error, seguramente conceptual, porque no lo estaría viendo:

```sql
select * from empleado C  
full outer join           
( 
    select  A.nDIEmp , A.nomEmp, A.jefeID , A.salEmp
    from empleado A
    inner join  ( select e.nDIEmp from empleado e where e.nDIEmp <> '31.840.269'  ) B 
    on A.jefeID = B.nDIEmp  and A.salEmp > 1000000  
) D 
on C.nDIEmp = D.nDIEmp 
where C.nDIEmp is null or D.nDIEmp is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Que quieres quieres seleccionar, por encima me parece que el primer full outer join es redundante, si seleccionas A.* en el query interno tendrias el registro empleado completo, adicionalmente el where C.nDIEmp is null te selecciona a los empleados que tienen ese campo en null, ¿esto es un id de empleado?, ¿tienen empleados con ese campo en nulo?, adicionalmente el join con B tambien es redundante, yo reescribiria ese query de esta forma:

```
select * from empleado where jefeID<>'31.840.269' and salEmp > 1000000
```

este query te da el listado de los empleados cuyo jefe NO es el '31.840.269' y ganan mas de 1000000, alli agregas las condicones que te hagan falta si es el caso.

Otro consejo evita hacer joins con el resultado de un select, por que se pierde cualquier optimizacion que puedan proporcionarte los indicies de las tablas involucradas en el join, procura siempre hacer los join solo entre tablas